# Java.Scanner не записывает данные в переменную

Tags: java

Доброе время суток, проблема заключается в том, что когда я записываю данные в переменную, пропускается запись из консоли и в переменную ничего не записывается, в чем проблема?

```
System.out.println("Выберите действие :\n1 - добавление записи\n2 - удаление записи\n3 - показать все записи\n4 - обновить запись\n5 - поместить данные из бд в XML\n6 - выход");

int number = scanner.nextInt();
switch (number) {
    case 1:
        String s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7, s8, s9, s10;
        System.out.println("Задайте город ученика");
        s1 = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Задайте школу ученика");
        s2 = scanner.nextLine();
        break;
}
```

в s1 ничего не записывается, а в s2 считывается с консоли

Comment: Код как-то не так отформатирован, но я не вижу в нем инициализацию scanner. Для решения проблемы ее желательно прикрепить @VaHHiLLiH

Comment: Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

Comment: сорян, я табуляцию расставлял, но результат печален, я сканер в другой класс передаю, вдруг это важно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Причина проблемы:**

Сначала нужно понять как работает `scanner.nextLine()`. Он дочитывает строку (по факту, он движется по массиву байт из `InputStream` консоли, т.е. из `System.in`) до её конца (до `\n`, либо `\r\n`, в зависимости от среды), после чего останавливается на первом же символе после символа(ов) конца строки, а все что он прочитал (за исключением символа(ов) конца строки он возвращает в качестве результата вызова).

Перед `switch` вы вызываете `scanner.nextInt()`, который считывает число из `InputStream` консоли и останавливает свой указатель на первым же символе после окончания числа, в вашем случае, т.к. после ввода числа вы нажали `enter` у вас там находится символ(ы) перевода строки.

Внутри `case 1:` у вас вызывается `scanner.nextLine()`, который согласно вышеописанному механизму читает все символы до конца строки и останавливается, но в вашем случае он уже стоял на символе конца строки, поэтому он просто сдвинул свой указатель на первый же символ после символа(ов) конца строки и остановился, а в результате своего вызова вернул пустую строку (`""`).

**Решение проблемы:**

Самый простой для вас способ: написать `scanner.nextLine();` сразу же после вызова `scanner.nextInt();` для перевода `scanner` на следующую строку (указатель в считываемом `InputStream` смещается на первый символ после символа(ов) конца текущей строки), где ввод символа контра строки еще не был осуществлен (т.к. её ввод, вообще, еще не был осуществлен).

Альтерантивный способ решения проблемы: изначально вместо `nextInt()` использовать `nextLine()` после чего самостоятельно выполнить парсинг значения `int` посредством статического метода `Integer.parseInt()`:

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Выберите действие:");
        System.out.println("1 - добавление записи;");
        System.out.println("2 - удаление записи;");
        System.out.println("3 - показать все записи;");
        System.out.println("4 - обновить запись;");
        System.out.println("5 - поместить данные из бд в XML;");
        System.out.println("6 - выход.");

        int number = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
        switch (number) {
            case 1: {
                System.out.println("Задайте город ученика:");
                String s1 = scanner.nextLine();

                System.out.println("Задайте школу ученика:");
                String s2 = scanner.nextLine();
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**Рекомендации:**

Не вижу сакрального смысла в объявлении переменных заранее, так сказать, Pascal Style (в вашем случае:`String s1, s2, ...`). Объявляйте переменные в месте первого использования (в вашем случае при вызоне `nextLine()`).

Comment: @StatrltPrimitive Спасибо большое за объяснения!))